# Unable to use logger for task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a situation where there is a synchronous call to a method and based on a parameter we switch the response for sync /async and inside async we start a task as below. The problem is tracer works until its outside the Task() but not inside. Is it happening that Task cannot access the parent thread data ?

RequestProcessor.cs file code:

```
public classA_Res GetListbyUserRequest(ApiRequest<object> request)
{
    if(request.IsAsync)
    {
        LocalTracer.TraceInformation(AVEventType.Info, "Async call started"); // this works/ gets logged in db
        var taskProcessEventsResponseAsync = new Task(() =>
            ProcessResponseAsync(validatedInputs, options, grids, userInfo, traceRequest, exportAs, userRequestId, sessionId));
        taskProcessEventsResponseAsync.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        response=DataManager.Instance.GetListbyUserRequest(); // this gets paginated data for UI
    }
    //some code for response that request has been put down for export async.
}
```

```
private void ProcessResponseAsync(validatedInputs, options, grids, userInfo, traceRequest, exportAs, userRequestId, sessionId)
{
    LocalTracer.TraceInformation(AVEventType.Info, "Async call in progress"); // this doesnt works/ doesnt gets logged in db but also doesnt throws any error
    
    //some code for processing data in chunks and creating files on server
}
```

LocalTracer.cs

```
public interface ILocalTracer
{
    void TraceInformation(AVEventType eventType, DummyParameter dummy = null);
}
```

```
public sealed class LocalTracer:ILocalTracer
{
   static ILocalTracer _instance = new LocalTracer();
   
    public static ILocalTracer Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
        set { _instance = value; }
    }

    private LocalTracer()
    {
       
    }

    public static void TraceInformation(AVEventType eventType, string sMessage = "", string 
    userName = "", string ipAddress = "",.....)
    {
        //tracer code
    }
    public void TraceInformation(AVEventType eventType, DummyParameter dummy = null)
    {
        TraceInformation(eventType, "");
    }
}
```

Please assume all this code in proper try catch blocks.

Comment: Threads do not have a parent-child relationship.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ok so i might be mixing thread and task but can you suggest something if possible please for the above scenario

Comment: Shalini Raj unfortunately not. Your question is a bit too complex for me to comprehend. My previous comment was based just on the title of the question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias np. thanks anyway